# @foreach loop with limit() function, not working well in laravel 8

Tags: eloquent, foreach, laravel-8, laravel-blade, limit

My laravel version is 8.83.27 and php is 7.4.26.
I want to loop through and display 6 posts from my posts table, so i set the limit to 6, but it only loop to 3 and stops, no matter the limit once its above 3, it doesn't go beyond 3.

this is my code:

```
@extends('FrontEnd.master')

@section('title')
    Home
@endsection


@section('content')

<div class="top-news">

    <div class="top-inner">

        @foreach ($posts as $post)

            <div class="col-md-6 top-text two">

                <a href="single.html">
                  <img src="{{ asset('/Source/front') }}/images/pic2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </a>

                <h5 class="top"><a href="single.html">Consetetur sadipscing elit</a></h5>

                <p>
                   Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt.
                </p>

                <p>On Jun 27 
                    <a class="span_link" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>0 </a>
                    <a class="span_link" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>56 </a>
                    <a class="span_link" href="single.html">
                       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span>
                    </a>
                </p>

            </div>

         @endforeach

        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        
    </div>

</div>

@endsection
```

my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FrontController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index()
    {
        
        $posts = Post::where('status','public')->latest()->limit(4)->get();
        //dd($posts);

       
        return view('FrontEnd.include.home',compact('posts'));
    }

}
```

i tried the
dd($posts) function and it gave this:

[image: three results]

please i need some help, thanks.

Comment: just to verify, are there more than 3 posts in the DB?

Comment: yes, there are 8 posts in the posts table in the DB